# Template not updating in parent observable for array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable with some properties, one property is an array. This array sends to child. When I log the output of the child, I see the data is being changed but when I look at the HTML, the parent HTML of the array is not seen, as a result the child html can't be seen. I also tried adding `ChangeDetection`.

The account looks something like:

```
account = {
  school: 'high school',
  person: Person[]
}
```

`(account $ | async)?.school` does update in parent.

Parent:

```
this.account$ = this.service.observeAccount
```

Parent HTML: When there is an update

```
<div class="row"> <!-- It does not show anything under row when the values changes.. -->
    <div class="col-lg-4" *ngFor="let person of (account$ | async)?.person">
       <app-demo [person]="person" *ngIf="person.url"></app-demo>
   </div>
</div>
```

Child: I can see it comes here

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes.person.currentValue !== changes.person.previousValue) {
      this.person= changes.person.currentValue
      console.log(this.person)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried the this.cdr.detectChanges(); method for re render?

Comment: Could you please add more details about the code you used to change the data?

Comment: @AlejandroBarone yes, I did. I tried `this.cd.detectChanges()`, as well as `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`

Comment: @Amer The data comes from service, which updates the values. The parent component observes from that service. `this.account$ = this.service.observeAccount`. `account$.school` can be seen updated in parent, but the array passing to child is not updated in HTML and cannot be seen in parent (strange!), but is being passed into the child component and can be seen in `console.log`. I also used `ngOnChanges` and it does get logged to child.

Comment: If the `<app-demo>` is the child you're talking about, and you can see the changes there in `ngOnChanges`, then it's rendered correctly and the parent's `*ngFor` is getting the changes and looping through the `(account$ | async)?.person` array. If that is your situation, then the problem is in your child component, which is not rendering anything inside it for some reason, so you need to check it correctly to figure the problem out.

Comment: @Amer but when I refresh the page, the render is correct. Without refresh, the `*ngFor` in parent `class="col-lg-4"` is not seen. Wouldn't it be a parent's problem?

Comment: Could you please share the child html?